# Помогите разобраться с получением контакта библиотека telebot / python / telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Помогите понять, в чем ошибка, что не так делаю?

Нужно после нажатия кнопки - попросить контакт (должен предложить кнопку получения контакта, ну и после её нажатия, получить контакт).

```
# main.py
import telebot, cfg, kb, lg
from telebot import types
from requests import get
import requests

bot = telebot.TeleBot(cfg.token)

@bot.message_handler(regexp=f'^{lg.rbtn5e}$')
def phone(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lg.hello6e, reply_markup=kb.rkbu3)

    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def contact(message):
    if message.contact is not None:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lg.hello6u, reply_markup=kb.rkbu4)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["location"])
def location(message):
    if message.location is not None:
        coord = str(message.location.longitude) + ',' + str(message.location.latitude)
        r = requests.get('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=' + apikey + '&format=json&kind=house&geocode=' + coord)
        
        if len(r.json()['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']) > 0:
            address = r.json()['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty'][
                'GeocoderMetaData']['text']
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Отлично, Теперь я знаю Ваш адрес. \n\n{}'.format(address))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lg.hello5u, reply_markup=kb.rkbu2)
        else:
             bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Упссс)   n\nПроверьте правильность Вашей геолокации ')


# lg.py
rbtn4u = "☎️ Отправить Ваш контакт"
rbtn4e = " Отправить местоположение"

rbtn3e = " Указать на карте "
rbtn3u = "⛪ Выбрать место"
rbtn5e = "‍ Cообщить оператору"
rbtn5u = "Отлично получил Ваш контакт"


# kb.py
import telebot, lg, cfg
from telebot import types

trkm = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup
button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(lg.rbtn4u, request_contact=True)
button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(lg.rbtn4e, request_location=True)

#tostartlocation kb
rkbu1 = trkm(True, True, row_width=1)
rkbu1.add(button_geo)

#endlocation kb
rkbu2 = trkm(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
rkbu2.add(lg.rbtn3e, lg.rbtn3u, lg.rbtn5e)

#startcontact kb
rkbu3 = trkm(True, True, row_width=1)
rkbu3.add(button_phone)

#endcontact kb
rkbu4 = trkm(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
rkbu4.add(lg.rbtn5u)
```

Comment: `в чем ошибка`, какая ошибка? Если есть ошибка -- напишите ее, если что-то не работает опишите проблему

Comment: Вот тоже 2-е сутки борюсь), не пойму в чем дело), не запрашивает тел! нажимаешь на кнопку rkbu3, и все), не пойму что ему не нравицо))

Comment: Блин, эти зашифрованные названия переменных убивают `rbtn3e`, `rbtn3u`, .... У них есть система в названии? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если клавиатуру в `phone` нужно показать при работе с кнопками из `rkbu2` (`rbtn3e = " Указать на карте "`, `rbtn3u = "⛪ Выбрать место"`, `rbtn5e = "‍ Cообщить оператору"`), то нужно не на команду `/number` обрабатывать метод, а на текст из кнопки.

Например через регулярку указывам, что ждем текст с полным совпадением с `lg.rbtn5e` (аналогичное можно сделать через лямбду, проверив текст из `message`)

Попробуйте:

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp=f'^{lg.rbtn5e}$')
def phone(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lg.rbtn4u, reply_markup=kb.rkbu3)
```

Comment: Подправил код), и расширил предисторию, Бот получает локацию тут все ок, далее предлагает выбор из 3-х кнопок, тут все тоже ок, одна отвечает за контакт, при нажатии ничего не происходит), из бота не выкидывает, весят эти же 3 кнопки),

Comment: @АрнольдПаладьев, обновил ответ

Comment: Огромный Респект!!!!! Низкий поклон! Очень выручили!!! Еще раз Благодарю!

Comment: @АрнольдПаладьев, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Доброго времени еще разок! Все бьюсь с получение контакта  от пользователя! помогите плиз реализовать ответ бота на получение контакта, в этом же примере! Благодарю!

Comment: @АрнольдПаладьев, используйте функцию с `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])` и в ней напишите сообщение юзеру

Comment: Огромный Респект! Благодарю!